# Ajax with jQuery returns error when all is fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling AJAX by jQuery to the script on the same domain, everything is successful, data are in the database etc, but AJAX still gives me back error. I tried to do output in JSON, didn't help. It was working just fine yesterday, but it's not working now.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.thirst4water.org/api/?request=sign_petition"+query_string,
        success: function(data){   // Ajax successfull
            alert('Request successful and id is'+data);
            // Hide loader
            $('.join-us .loader').hide();  

            // If return is numeric we have id, if not we have error
            if (isNumber(data)){
                window.userId = data;   // Save gobally new user id
                $('.join-us').fadeOut();    // Hide the Signing form        

                // If we have userPic that means user came from facebook, and can skip uploading of picture     
                if(window.userPic){
                    // Store avatar from facebook
                    tomUploadAvatar(window.userPic);

                    // Switch the steps
                    $('#step2').fadeOut('normal',function(){
                        $('#step3').fadeIn();  // Let's see the final step 
                    });

                    // And re-load the dragon
                    tomReloadDragonPerson(window.userId);                                                                                                               
                } else {
                    $('.join-us').fadeOut('normal',function(){  // Hide the Signing form
                        $('#step2').fadeIn();   // In case we didnt come from facebook we show uploading form
                    });                 
                }
            } else {
                $('.join-us .actions').html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(value1,value2,value3){
            alert(JSON.stringify(value1)+JSON.stringify(value2)+JSON.stringify(value3));
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

The PHP script is fine, if I just open the address everything works fine.

Comment: Btw this is what i get (error): {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"},"error",""

Comment: does the php script have the correct headers? e.g. `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: is there a need for json? I will try just for test to set the headers

Comment: if you can use firebug and check the response with the console that you get back from the server

Comment: @Henesnarfel I did use firegub, but there is no response. It shows me what am I sending but doesnt show any response - just blank

Comment: @Tom is it possible to give us the php? Also can we access the site where this is being done to help debug with you.

Comment: If it was working yesterday and you've not changed the code then it must be the data that is causing the problem.  Can you show us the returned data from the php call?

Comment: might be a cross domain issue. Check it on different browsers once.

Comment: If you want to see returned data you can access: http://www.thirst4water.org/api/?request=sign_petition&name=Stack&email=stack@stack.com You will either get number (id) or string (Right now output is not in JSON, it didnt help anyway.). It gets even stranger, cause Right now its working for me, but doesnt work on any other computer.... I am having feeling that Facebook js script or ajax upload script could block it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
url: "http://www.thirst4water.org/api/?request=sign_petition"+query_string,
success: function(data){   // Ajax successfull
```

to this

```
url: "http://www.thirst4water.org/api/?request=sign_petition"+query_string,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){   // Ajax successfull
```

Comment: Seems like it was crossdomain problem, if i remove the domain name and keep just /api/... it does work, anyway they decided that they want it other way again so this is not relevant anyore. But thank you for help!